# Why do heat pumps use a separate “reversing” signal from thermostats?

Tags: thermostat, heat-pump

Thermostats use a W signal to call for heat and Y for cool.  For heat pumps they also have an O or a B signal to "reverse" the pump into the appropriate heating or cooling mode.

Why two signals?

Why can't the pump reversal follow the appropriate W or Y signal?  Why is there a separate but identical signal to reverse one component, the pump, for heating or cooling? The thermostat does not generally control all the system components separately.  If the thermostat calls for heat, the system should do whatever it needs to do to produce heat.  Why does one part, the pump, need its own command?

Comment: Read the heat pump's manual. It will usually explain things like this.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've tried looking at various heat pump manuals.  Not yet seen an explanation.  Basically, the thermostat manuals and heat pump manuals always say that if the <other end> has a O/B terminal, connect it "here".  That's it. No further explanation.  I can't even fathom how a consumer thermostat would have logic to control a heat pump direction valve independently of its pump.   Any such logic would, I think, be proprietary to the logic board of the pump.

Comment: Jay this topic was covered in hvac training and not one student in the class knew the real reason some close guesses. The short cycle timer sometimes built into the thermostat is part of the operation

Comment: @EdBeal I was imagining that a thermostat could keep the valve in the direction of the previous cycle in anticipation that the next cycle will be the same.  IE, if you just cooled, keep the valve as "cool" because that's probably what's next.   And somehow, that would be better than flapping the valve every cycle.  But that's a guess and I have no basis for it, and I'd be surprised if any $50 thermostat with an O/B terminal actually does that.

Comment: Jay, a simple power bump will kill your argument. It takes power on a single element valve to keep it in the opposite position or one position is normal the other is powered heating or cooling and even cheap ac  thermostats have short cycle timers and have for 30 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is because control boards and programmable thermostats are recent inventions

The concept of a "control board" in a piece of HVAC gear is a fairly recent invention, dating back to the 1980s or so when single-chip microcontrollers started to become inexpensive/widely available.  Before then, if you wanted anything more intelligent than direct control of the various pieces of equipment (burner or element, fan, compressor, reversing valve), you had to do it the hard way with relays, sensing switches, and dedicated timer boards, such as found in the fan/limit system of a pre-control-board gas furnace, or the dedicated timer defrost controls in early heat pump systems.  Furthermore, programmable thermostats as we know them today also aren't any older than control boards, while heat pumps and heat pump thermostats date back to well before we had any of this solid-state stuff roaming around.

As a result, what you had with early heat pumps was a bimetal thermostat with extra contacts on its mode switches sending control signals *directly* to the compressor contactor and reversing valve on the heat pump's outdoor unit, or to a dedicated defrost timer/relay that could override the thermostat to initiate defrost.  This saved money on extra relays in the outdoor unit at the cost of requiring (cheaper) switch contacts in the heat pump thermostat, and a slight bit of extra wiring in the walls.

Furthermore, the use of a separate signal allowed the reversing valve to be kept in the same "idle" state across cycles during both heating and cooling operation without further logic inside the outdoor unit, as the O/B signal's state does not depend on whether the thermostat is commanding a cycle or not.  This is important because reversing, while simple to implement, puts non-trivial stresses on the rest of the heat pump, so you don't want to "swap ends" unnecessarily.  Unfortunately, some zone boards exploit this behavior by require both an O *and* a B wire, which makes installing a modern thermostat on them a non-trivial proposition.

Comment: If I understand this, it's really simple.  Are you saying that O or B are controlled by the *mode*, ie in Cool or Heat mode, regardless of temperature, O or B are consistently in the state that represents the mode?   So if you have a "normally cooling" valve, then in the winter when you switch on Heat, B becomes and remains energized 24/7 regardless of the call for heat or for air circulation?   Is that how it works?

Comment: @jay613 -- yes, that's how it works

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a double ended solenoid once it moves it stays there. O moves the valve from heat to cool and it stays there. B moves the valve from cooling to heating.

This is better than having a single spring loaded valve because a minor power bump will dump the pressure in the loop and that would be hard on the entire system coils and lines included.

With the valves requiring force of a solenoid to move them they stay in heat or cool. Many systems require a 3-7 minute off period for the compressor so there is not pressure in the loop to make the change because it’s that hard on the system.

Think of it this way one side may be close to 400 psi depending on refrigerant the other side 100 so there may be a 300 psi thump for a power fault on a spring loaded valve, now it makes sense why they want to force them each way allowing the pressure to equalize and not have the thump.

Comment: I do not believe this is correct.  The reverse valves according to my reading have a normal state and an energized one.  And they have EITHER an O or a B terminal.  If the solenoid were not spring-loaded it would need to remain energized in either state, which is not the case, and it would need two different signals, which I haven't seen in any heat pump documentation.   More importantly, regardless of all that, even if your explanation were correct the functionality you describe could be achieved with JUST the W or Y signal.  They are identical to the O and B signals.  THAT is the question!

Comment: To be clearer, if there is a thermostat and heat pump combination that require, and use, BOTH O and B to achieve the forward and reverse states, and when both are de-energized nothing happens, I have not seen such a thing and I suspect if it existed it would be a proprietary complete system ... you couldn't use a consumer stat with such a pump.

Comment: @jay613 https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/183676/42053 seems to agree with Ed's answer as far as why O/B exist. As for the actual mechanics inside of the heat pump; I would trust Ed =)

Comment: Jay I do have some training and I am telling you what the training I received. after answering I did check to make sure I has O&B the correct direction and  most thermostats have a short cycle timer that prevents the system from restarting within the programmed time this is to prevent the compressor overheating from trying to start with high pressure on the output. Every AC or Heat pump rated thermostat I have installed has the short cycle safety, if your experience is limited I am surprised you challenge without knowledge.

Comment: @EdBeal I respect the training and attempts to get through to me.  I think I'm just not following the whole thread of thought.   I understand the short cycle timer. My A/C has one in the thermostat and one in the blower logic board, and another timer that cycles the fan randomly.  Altogether this makes it confusing to determine when to expect the compressor to come on or not.   All this is just to say, I get it about the short cycle timer.  What I don't understand is how the short cycle timer relates to the need for the reverse valve and the pump to be controlled separately.  Continued ...

Comment: W and Y , as I understand them, can set the valve to the correct direction and start the pump.   The short cycle timer would do its job just as with a regular A/C.  And if I understand what you are saying about the solenoid (which apparently I do not) .... if it is "sticky" (never resets itself) then it will always be in position to accept a restart when the timer is ready for it.